# How to pass perl variable into backticks within double quotes

Tags: perl

I am writing a perl script where I need to pass a perl variable into backticks and also the variable should be declared inside of double quotes into that backticks. *ex : my $variable=`df -Ph | grep -i "$var1"`*

Comment: I saw this thread already but I didnt get it what I need. In my query the command which I am going to execute inside of backticks is very complicated only which should contain multiple double quotes, single quotes, forward slashes at all.. when I am passing the perl variable inside of double quotes its not taking up.

Answer (score 5):

I *think* what you're asking is that you have something which contains shell meta-characters (like quotes and slashes). You want to use that in a shell command, but you don't want the meta-characters to be treated literally.  For example...

```
my $search = q[don't look now];
my @results = `df -Ph | grep -i $search`
```

There's several ways to deal with this.  Rather than fiddle around with shell quoting, simplest is to escape all the meta-characters.  Perl has [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) to do this.

```
my $search = q[don't look now];
my $q_search = quotemeta($search);  # don\'t\ look\ now
my @results = `df -Ph | grep -i $q_search`
```

Or you can do it in place with `\Q` and `\E`.

```
my $search = q[don't look now];
my @results = `df -Ph | grep -i \Q$search\E`
```

Instead I would recommend avoiding the shell as much as possible, it introduces incompatibilities and security holes.  You need to do the `df` in shell, but do the grep in Perl.

```
my $search = q[don't look now];
my @results = grep /\Q$search\E/i, `df -Ph`;
```